# Overriding orchard view template

Tags: orchardcms, overriding, view-templates

I want to customize/change html/css of the login page (~/Modules/Orchard.Users/Views/LogOn.cshtml).

I created a cshtml file under the themes folder (Themes - MyCustomTheme - Views - LogOn.cshtml) with the same name. This didn't work. How can I override the main LogOn.cshtml from my custom theme?

Edit:

If I enable shape tracer, this is what I see,

Active Template: ~/Modules/Orchard.Users/Views/LogOn.cshtml ​

Alternate (1): ~/Themes/SafeMode/Views/LogOn.cshtml

Thanks.

Comment: What version of orchard are you using?

Answer (score 2):

LogOn is just a shape as anything else, so you can override it as you did in your own theme (this theme must be active of course)

It can happen that it does not instantly get picked up by Orchard, so you could try to reset the site/application pool.